# Can $y = x^\sqrt{3}$ be considered a Power function? What about a polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

Can $$y = x^\sqrt{3}$$ be considered a Power function? What about a polynomial?

Also, is $$y = \sqrt{3}^x$$ an exponential?

I am curious about the boundaries which define each type of function.

Thank you.

Comment: $x^{\sqrt{3}}$ is a power function, but not a polynomial, since $\sqrt{3}$ is not an integer.

Comment: ${\sqrt 3}^x$ is certainly an exponential function, since it can be written in the form $e^{kx}$, where $k=\ln \sqrt3$.

Comment: A polynomial is a sum of terms like a*x^b where the b's must be non-negative integers.  So the first is not a polynomial.  It is a power function, since x^b is a power function for any b.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. For functions that are in fact polynomials, can we consider them algebraic equations?

Comment: No, polynomials and functions are not equations.